# Reserve memory per task in SLURM

Tags: slurm

We're using SLURM to manage job scheduling on our computing cluster, and we experiencing a problem with memory management. Specifically, we can't find out how we can allocate memory for a specific task.

Consider the following setup:

- Each node has 32GB memory
- We have a SLURM job that sets `--mem=24GB`

Now, assume we want to run that SLURM job twice, concurrently. Then what I expect (or want) to happen is that when I queue it twice by calling `sbatch runscript.sh` twice, one of the two jobs will run on one node, and the other will run on another node. However, as it currently is, SLURM schedules both tasks on the same node.

One of the possible causes we've identified is that it appears to check only whether the 24GB of memory is *available* (i.e., not actively used by other node), instead of checking whether it is requested/allocated.

The question here is: **is it possible to allocate/reserve memory per task in SLURM?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the value in slurm.conf for SelectTypeParams?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! `SelectType=select/cons_res` and `SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to manage memory slurm needs the parameter in SchedTypeParameters to include MEMORY. So just changing that parameter to `CR_Core_Memory` should be enough for Slurm to start to manage the memory.

If that is not set --mem will not reserve memory and only ensure that the node has enough memory configured.

More information [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/cons_res.html)

Comment: Thanks, Carles! I appreciate your help! Setting that parameter to `CR_Core_Memory` will indeed make memory (alongside cores) a consumable resource.

Answer (score 2):

@CarlesFenoy's answer is good, but to answer

> The question here is: is it possible to allocate/reserve memory per
> task in SLURM?

the parameter you are looking for is `--mem-per-cpu`, to use in combination with `--cpus-per-task`

Comment: Thanks for your comment; this is indeed the way to allocate memory once you've specified that memory is a consumable resource. Thanks! I'm marking Carles' answer as the accepted answer, but I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I am currently using this way, but it still seems not the best. I do not know the appropriate parameter of `mem-per-cpu`. Some cluster has fat node and standard node. If my task actually only use one core, the other cores will be wasted since I need to specify a big core number to satisfy the mem requirement.